# How to get notified when the thread that performs a database operation returning a LiveData is finished?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

Database operations that return LiveData are automatically executed on a background thread. I need to do some "post-processing" on the returned LiveData in order to add information from another table.

However, my code to perform this processing executes too early, before the LiveData is actually returned
from the thread that performs the Dao call.  Eventually, the LiveData-wrapped list is successfully populated, but its Person objects do not contain the data that I'd intended to augment them with (i.e., the possession data).

What I'd like to do, unless someone can suggest a better overall approach, is to ensure that the method that performs the post-processing, aggregatePersonData, is invoked after the LiveData is returned from the query thread.

The following pared-down code snippets illustrate my approach.

```
// Person.java
@Entity(tableName = "People")
public class Person
{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;

    // ...

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // ...
}


// from PersonDao.java
@Query("SELECT * FROM People ORDER BY last_name")
LiveData<List<AggregatePerson>> getAllPeople();


// PeoplePossessions is a one-to-many table (i.e., one Person to many Possessions).


// from PersonPossessionDao
@Query("SELECT p.* FROM Possessions p INNER JOIN PeoplePossessions pp ON p.id = pp.possession_id WHERE pp.person_id=:personId")
LiveData<List<Possession>> getPossessionsForPerson(final long personId);


// (not an entity)
// AggregatePerson.java
public class AggregatePerson extends Person
{
    // fields from a join between the People table and (an)other table(s) would go here...

    @Ignore
    private List<String> mPossessions;

    // ...  

    public List<String> getPossessions()
    {
        return mPossessions;
    }

    public void setPossessions(List<String> possessions)
    {
        mPossessions = possessions;
    }
}


// MyRepository.java
public class MyRepository
{
    private PersonDao mPersonDao;
    private PersonPossessionDao mPersonPossessionDao;

    private LiveData<List<AggregatePerson>> mAllPeople;

    public MyRepository(Application application)
    {
        PersonDatabase database = PersonDatabase.getInstance(application);

        // Room automatically executes database operations that return  
        // LiveData objects on a background thread.
        mPersonDao = database.personDao();
        mAllPeople = mPersonDao.getAllPeople();

        mPersonPossessionDao = database.personPossessionDao();
    }

    //...

    public LiveData<List<AggregatePerson>> getAllPeople()
    {
        aggregatePersonData(mAllPeople.getValue());
        return mAllPeople;
    }

    // This method executes too early, before the LiveData<List<AggregatePerson>>
    // has been populated. Thus, the code that adds the possession data is skipped.
    private void aggregatePersonData(List<AggregatePerson> people)
    {
        if (null != people)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

            // In this loop, a query is performed for each person.
            for (AggregatePerson person : people)
            {
                long personId = person.getId();
                List<Possession> possessions = mPersonPossessionDao.getPossessionsForPerson(personId);
                if (null != possessions)
                {
                    items.clear();
                    sb.setLength(0);
                    for (int i = 0; i < possessions.size(); i++)
                    {
                        Possession possession = possession.get(i);
                        sb.append(possession.getName());
                        sb.append(": ");
                        sb.append(possession.getValue());
                        sb.append(", ");
                        sb.append(possession.getWeight());
                        items.add(sb.toString());
                    }
                    person.setPossessions(items);
                }

                // more data aggregation for current person would go here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the whole point of LiveData is for the View to observe Model data changes, I've moved the data aggregation/manipulation code from the Model layer to the View layer.  There, I can respond when the various queries are finished, aggregate the data, and store it in the ViewModel for future use by the UI Controller. So far, the approach seems valid.

Comment: Update: Discovered that observations can be made at the ViewModel layer afterall by using MediatorLiveData.  Each "source" can be observed, so I can now perform the data aggregation in the ViewModel and have all the data ready-to-go for the UI Controller.  I also employed a CountdownLatch to only set the value on the MediatorLiveData once all the data aggregation is complete.  The latch count is decremented in the onChanged() method for each source added to the MediatorLiveData. Now, there's no UI flicker as new data arrives, because all the data is collected before it's displayed.